# Analyse and report disk usage growth historically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, disk-space

Is it possible to use historic information to show disk usage growth?

I haven't keep much in the way of database setup and disk usage information. So I can't say how much disk growth has occurred in the last 6/12/18 months.

Can I reconstruct that picture from info stored somewhere in SQL Server?

Comment: No, SQL Server does not keep history of information like this. The best you might be able to do is review file growth events from the default trace, but that is not the whole picture at all (and is only going to go back so far, depending on how busy the server is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DBs reside on a SAN or other shared storage that platform may have logs you can reference.  For local storage I know of nothing held by default.

A couple of years ago we started tracking DB size and disk free/used space. It has proved very valuable.  A couple of Powershell scripts, a scheduled task and a small table has helped us avoid several incidents.  Eventually we had enough data to make Monte Carlo prediction workable.